# $_POST only contains the last input textbox value

Tags: php, html, forms, post

Consider the simple form:

```
<form method="POST" action="test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">                
   <div id="caseInfo">
       <p> Enter some text</p>
       <input type=text name="sEvent" /> 

       <p> Enter some more text</p>
       <input type=text name="sEvent" /> 
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Send">
 </form>
```

In my php file I simply read `var_dump($_POST);` and get the following output:

```
array(1) { ["sEvent"]=> string(3) "Hey" }
```

"Hey" is what I wrote in the last textbox, how do I retrieve the value for both, when they have the same name?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225644/php-using-post-when-mutliple-form-fields-share-same-name-id

Comment: Your input fields all have the same name, so you'll only see the last. Either change the names, or use `sEvent[]` as the name, and PHP will create an array in `$_POST['sEvent']` instead of a single value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use an array in post data, the name must end in [], like

```
<input type=text name="sEvent[]" />
```

Comment: Is that the case for both occurences of "sEvent" so both needs to have [] appended to them?

Answer (score 1):

You have to give each input element a unique name

```
   <p> Enter some text</p>
   <input type=text name="sEvent1" /> 

   <p> Enter some more text</p>
   <input type=text name="sEvent2" />
```

Or define it as an array as David mentioned

```
   <p> Enter some text</p>
   <input type=text name="sEvent[]" /> 

   <p> Enter some more text</p>
   <input type=text name="sEvent[]" />
```