# Button can't save first item when clicked

Tags: laravel

In a `foreach` loop, I have more than one item and each item has a button called "save". However, when I click on the first "save" button, it saves only the last item in my database.

```html
@foreach($product_dr as $product)
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 20px;color: #101010">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" name="title" value="{{$product->title}}">
                <label for="inputText3" class="col-form-label"></label>
                {{$product->title}}
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="font-size: 20px;color: #2ec551">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="inputText4"   VALUE="{{$product->price}}" type="text" name="price" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount" style="width: 100px">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="font-size: 20px;color: #2ec551">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="inputText4"  VALUE="1" type="number" name="amount" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount" style="width: 100px">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="font-size: 20px;color: #2ec551">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" name="table" value="{{$table[0]->number}}">
                <input type="hidden" name="table_number" value="{{$table[0]->number}}">
                <label for="inputText3" class="col-form-label"></label>
                {{$table[0]->number}}
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 ">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: using post when mutliple form fields share same name & id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225644/php-using-post-when-mutliple-form-fields-share-same-name-id)

Answer (score 0):

The name of the variables must be an array as such:

```
<input type="hidden" name="title[]" value="{{$product->title}}">
```

This way you will have an array on your backed that you can iterate.  If not, you will only get one value for "title"